# What is the maximum possible frequency and wavelength?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

As a start I assumed [Planck angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_angular_frequency) which is the reciprocal of [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) as the frequency upper limit, but not so sure. On the other hand, is there a lower limit? Can we consider the reciprocal of our universe as a theoretical limit which is not yet limited, or just assume 0? I am just curious to know if you have any ideas with thanks.

Comment: The frecuency of what?

Comment: The photon frequency for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/2451 and links therein.