# Ultimate Planck Frequency

Tags: time, units, frequency, physical-constants

Is there an upper limit to the Planck Frequency?  Does it simply depend upon the inverse of the Planck Time unit?

Comment: What do you mean by "discuss"?

Comment: Well I would like you to add something about this topic. Specifically, do you believe there is an upper limit to EMR frequency?

Comment: I have reworded the question to satisfy the group rule on question format.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86531/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Well OK - why not answer both threads - they are slightly different.