# What is the lowest frequency of light that can be found in nature?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, wavelength

To be more specific can an electron emit any wavelength thus frequency of light and if so is it likely to do so in nature (outside lab)? I'am a student so excuse me if the question is illogical. Thank you for your time all answers are welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum frequency of an electromagnetic wave](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263484) or links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum wavelength of a photon/electromagnetic radiation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246896/)

Comment: That emit any wavelength is impossible due to quantum mechanics.