# What happens when the wavelength of light becomes as large as the observable universe?

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, universe, wavelength

Say the wavelength of a photon became so large that it approached the size of the observational universe. Does something unexpected happen?

Comment: What is unexpected for you?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246896/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there is no upper limit on the wavelength of a photon.

Since the whole universe is probably infinite, the observable universe is just a little part of it.

So when the photon's wavelength reaches the size of the observable universe, nothing unexpected happens, it can still keep growing.

Though, I would like to mention that the universe is expanding at an accelerating rate, and if the rate of acceleration reaches and surpasses the speed of light, then even the observable part of the universe could be expanding at a rate of higher then the speed of light. 
It is not clear how you would create this photon with this large of a wavelength.
The wavelength of the photon in this case will not be able to reach the size of this observable universe. By the time you create the photon, the observable universe will have expanded at a rate higher then the speed of light.

Comment: The current cosmological models may predict an expanding or an accelerating expansion but there's no physical evidence space is expanding.

Answer (score -2):

It would require more than a Hubble time to emit such a photon so it does not exist yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that would be the case and what mechanism you would see?

Comment: Nah, there are three responders that know better than me. It is their move now.

Comment: Unless it has red shifted? +1