If the human eye can handle electromagnetic waves with infinite wavelength, does this mean that it can see infinite colors?
I know that 99% of colors in nature are not a single wavelength, but a mixture of different wavelengths and human perception. Then, if humans can see electromagnetic waves with infinite wavelengths, and there are corresponding cone cells and photoreceptors to perceive their wavelengths and mix them, can they see infinite colors?

Human vision is limited to perceive only visible light which makes up just a small part of the EM spectrum (well, what does small mean in the context of a theoretically infinite spectrum? but you get my point). But you're not totally wrong in that, a continuous real number can take infinite values even within a finite segment.. so there are two questions mixed in here (about colors vs. EM wave length).

This question is similar to: Maximum wavelength of a photon/electromagnetic radiation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

An even more similar one is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467313 , but it is closed.

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837698/2451

Hi user468472. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Color is more complicated than wavelength. We can associate one color with every wavelength within a certain narrow band of wavelengths, but the reverse is not true. There are other colors, (e.g., "pink," "brown") that cannot be specified by simply naming a single wavelength of light. And, for wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation not in that narrow band, "color" simply has no meaning at all.

@SolomonSlow: A useful clarification but note the OP also said "mixtures".

Yes, that would be correct. But we have no way of knowing what these new colours could be as we obviously have no reference to decide by. Some reptiles can see into infrared and ultraviolet for example.

Please edit the original question instead of this repost.

@MoziburUllah, The question you see here has been edited so many times that there now is nothing left of the text on which I left that comment. There was no mention of "mixtures" in it anywhere.

@solomon slow: Fair enough.

I changed the title that is suspected to be repeated. What I really want to ask is "If the human eye can see electromagnetic waves with infinite wavelengths and the mixture of their wavelengths, can it see infinite colors" instead of "Is the ultimate wavelength or color of electromagnetic waves infinite?"

"Then, if humans can see electromagnetic waves with infinite wavelengths" is a non sequitur.

@user468472 The wavelength is usually a real number. Infinity is NOT a real number and is therefore not a possible value for it. In other words, there are infinitely many real numbers, but infinity is NOT one of them. So by "infinite wavelength", do you mean infinitely many wavelengths?

When I say infinite wavelength, I mean infinite length
