Does the limit of the longest wavelength of electromagnetic waves depend on the size of the observable universe or the size of the whole universe?
I don't know whether the limit wavelength of electromagnetic waves is determined by the size of the observable universe or the size of the whole universe.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246896/2451 and links therein.

I'm not sure if "wavelength" is a well-defined concept at such scales, but in principle, the formalism of classical electrodynamics allows for waves of any length.

“The whole Universe” is likely infinite, so a wavelength that long isn’t well-defined.

It doesn’t make sense to compare a length to a volume

I think you are trying to compare wavelength of electromagnetic wave to hubble radius not hubble volume.
