The upper limit of electromagnetic wave wavelength is the size of the universe, which means the observable universe or the whole universe?
show that the longest wavelength is determined by the size of the universe, which is correct, but it is not clear. I don't know whether it refers to the observable universe or the whole universe. Many documents show that the size of the universe may be infinite. If the universe is infinite, does it mean that there is no upper limit for the wavelength of electromagnetic waves?
相关文献https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-electromagnetic-spectrum-wavelengths-limits-and-the-universe.211148/

It doesn’t matter because neither option could ever happen in practice.

You have an unbalanced quotation mark. It would be better to fix that and also specify where you're quoting from.

I added relevant documents and corrected vague grammar and improper punctuation.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837698/2451

What does your first sentence mean? Also, the title and body contain different questions.
