# Is the electromagnetic spectrum bounded somehow?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

Is there a maximum frequency that an electromagnetic wave can support?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the minimum wavelength of electromagnetic radiation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is an approximate limit to the wavelengths (spectrum) emitted by an object of a given temperature: in fact, before quantum mechanics, there was a problem called the "UV catastrophe" where calculations of the spectrum suggested there should be infinite power in the shortest wavelengths; QM could explain away this problem, and it was one of the early triumphs of the theory.

But in principle there is no limit (that I know of) on the energy of an individual photon - and therefore, no upper limit on the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes(at least measurably). According to generalized uncertainty principle, the Planck length(1.616199e-35m)is the the shortest measurable length(within a factor of 10). So that can be the shortest wavelength possible.
Which gives maximum frequency to be 6.187356e34 Hz.
[Plank length - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_lenght)