What is the shortest/longest wavelength of a photon?
What are the largest/smallest possible wavelengths of photons? I am interested in what limits apply to photon creation.

Too many duplicates to count: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247227/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149632/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284585/

This question is similar to: Is the electromagnetic spectrum bounded somehow?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: What is the minimum wavelength of electromagnetic radiation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
