# Knowing more about electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

we have discovered from **radio waves** to **gamma rays** but there may possibilities of existence of other electromagnetic waves beyond this range which we haven't discovered it, may be the reason that our current technology not have that "EYE"  to see those waves. Is there any possibility of such waves having more frequency than gamma rays and wavelength than radio waves.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Radio waves do not have a low frequency limit. Anything lower in frequency than radio waves is still radio waves. Gamma rays do not have a high frequency limit. Anything higher in frequency than gamma rays is still gamma rays. Thus the entire spectrum is covered. The highest energy cosmic gamma rays detected to date were $10^{14}\,eV$ or $2.4\cdot 10^{28 }\,Hz$.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Those are only definitions for certain intervals of frequencies that are particularly useful for something. There is nothing, at least classically, that prevents eletromagnetic waves from having an arbitrary frequency (exept technical limitations).

PS: I think that historically X-rays and gamma rays were distinguished based on their source.

Comment: And they still are: x-rays come from electronic transitions, gamma rays from nuclear transitions.

Comment: Agree with Jon Custer. Tough is just matter of classification. There is frequency for something precise. Under the use of frequency the question, as it is posed, wouldn't be arise.