# What is minimum possible wavelength of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

Is it limited? Is the maximum possible wavelength limited?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the minimum wavelength of electromagnetic radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16391/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if we were to state a maximum or minimum possible wavelength (frequency and therefore energy) for light, there will always be a frame of reference where this wavelength
(frequency and energy) is arbitrary. In fact, an observer measures a wavelength $$\lambda_{o} = \lambda_s \sqrt{\frac{\left(1 + \frac{v}{c}\right)}{\left(1 - \frac{v}{c}\right)}}$$  where the source has a velocity $v$ relative to the observer (and $\lambda_s$ is the wavelength in the frame of the source with $c$ being the speed of light).

In other words, wavelength, frequency and energy are all quantities that depend on relative motion. So one could state that they observed an electromagnetic wave with wavelength $1$ *nanometer* but another observer in a boosted frame of reference can observe it with a wavelength of say, $10$ *meters* for example.

When talking about frame dependent quantities, terms like "maximum" or "minimum" essentially become meaningless.